# Place Image in PyQt QTableWidget Header

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem, qheaderview

I am trying to create a QTableWidget that has a thumbnail image in it's vertical header (and eventually some text under it). My current attempt is to subclass the QTableWidgetItem...

```py
class ShotHeader(qt.QTableWidgetItem):
    imagePath = os.path.join(r'T:\path\to\image.jpg')
    shotThumbnailPixMap = QPixmap(imagePath).scaledToWidth(60)

    def __init__(self):
        super(ShotHeader, self).__init__()
        self.setData(QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole, self.shotThumbnailPixMap)
```

And later on this is set via

```py
shotInterface = QTableWidget(rows, cols)
for row in range(rows):
    shotInterface.setVerticalHeaderItem(row, ShotHeader())
```

Which *does* show the image, but it seems to be an icon which I cannot change the size of, as can be seen in the following image...

[image: Tiny thumbnail images which will not change.]

Obviously, I'm looking for a way to make the images a decent size,
I have searched quite extensively for a solution to this problem, but have so far come up with nothing. No amount of scaling the QPixmap has any effect.
I'd really appreciate some help on this.

NB: I'm running PyQt in Houdini if that makes any difference.

Comment: Will all the images be the same in each row?

Comment: No, but for simplicity I have made it that way, so I'm just using the single shared QPixmap.

Comment: Do you want to get something like the following? https://imgur.com/a/YA4PLQ4

Comment: Yes, but with a larger image if possible.

Comment: Is it something like the following: https://imgur.com/a/j1Lru7s?

Comment: Yes...how did you achieve this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189741/discussion-between-anti-distinctlyminty-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: Wait a moment, I'm working on setting the size automatically, now the drawing is fine but now I'm manually changing the size of the cell

Comment: @eyllanesc Hello?

Comment: @eyllanesc We need you man!